# Set sbt's SettingKey only in certain command

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Let's say I have a SettingKey in one of my own SBT plugin:

```
object MySbtPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  ...
  object autoImport {
    object MyKeys {
      val task = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("task", "some task")
      val prod = SettingKey[Boolean]("prod", "Only enable when running `stage`.")
    }
  }

  val baseSettings = Seq(
    prod in task := false,

    vuefy in Assets := Def.task {
      val isProd = (prod in task).value
      ...
```

Now I want `prod` to be:

- `true` when running `sbt stage`
- but `false` when running `sbt run`. This is for Playframework.

I've tried many combinations in my `build.sbt`, and they don't seem to work. For example:

- `MyKeys.prod in VueKeys.vuefy in Assets := true` sets the value regardless; This is not what I want.
- `MyKeys.prod in VueKeys.vuefy := true` doesn't work. This really confuses me why it doesn't even set the value to true.
- `MyKeys.prod in VueKeys.vuefy in stage := true` doesn't work.

I don't think I understand how scoping works in SBT. If anyone can help me, that would be really great.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `prod := false` and `prod in Runtime := true`?

Comment: I'll try it. Can you explain more why you think this is right? Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.